# How can I correctly insert an object into an array (after a callback)?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to append a `User` object into an array. However, I only want to do so *after* its data has been downloaded.

```
var items = [User]()
for id in user_ids {
    let user = User(id: id)
    user.downloadData({ [weak self] in
        items.append(user) //will "user" be THIS instance?
    })
}
```

Ordering is important.  I also don't want any complications with duplicates, etc.

Inserting an instance into an array inside the callback of the same instance is making me wonder if I'm doing it correctly.

Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Yes it will be that instance. The only thing to note is that if you try to use items outside of the callback it may be used before all of some of your items are appended. I would make sure to update UI after modifying a model object in a callback.

Comment: If ordering is important, you should probably be concerned that by sending all the requests "at once" doesn't guarantee that they'll finish in the same order

Comment: Also does `downloadData` need to be an instance method? seems like it could be a class func of some sort.

Comment: Can you post more context? It's impossible to know what will actually happen. with just that snippet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same user. However, there's no guarantee that each user will finish in the same order with which you started it. Make 2 changes: (1) use a dictionary to store the downloaded data and (2) use Grand Central Dispatch to wait till all of them are downloaded:

```
// Assume user's ID is an Int
let userData = [Int: User]()
let groupID = dispatch_group_create()

for id in user_ids {
    let user = User(id: id)
    dispatch_group_enter(groupID)

    user.downloadData{ [weak self] in
        userData[id] = user
        dispatch_group_leave(groupID)
    }
}

// Wait until data for all users have been downloaded
dispatch_group_wait(groupID, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

// Now all users' data have been downloaded. If you want to put them
// into an array according to some order, do this:
let items = user_ids.map { userData[$0]! }
```